# I have to extract information like In which year did most of the employees join to the company? Display the year and number of employees

Tags: sql

```
select Hire, Max(Employee_Joins) Employee_Joins
from (select year(Hiredate) Hire, count(Ename) Employee_Joins
      from Employee
      group by year(Hiredate)
     ) Employee_Count
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Column 'Employee_Count.Hire' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ORDER BY` and a limit of some sort.  Your error message suggests SQL Server, so:

```
select top (1) year(Hiredate) Hire, count(*) as Employee_Joins
from Employee
group by year(Hiredate)
order by Employee_Joins desc;
```